# Examples for reductive Lie-groups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

I try to understand an excerpt from the book "Dirac Operators on Representation Theory" by Jing Song Huang and Pavle Pandzic. On page 9 we have following:

A Lie algebra $\frak{g}$ is called semisimple if it is a direct sum of simple ideals, and
reductive if it is the direct sum of its center and a semisimple ideal. For example,
$\frak{g}l(n, \mathbb{F})$ is reductive: it has a one-dimensional center consisting of scalar matrices,
and a direct complement to the center is the simple Lie algebra $\frak{sl}(n, \mathbb{F})$.

A Lie group $G$ is called semisimple if the Lie algebra of $G$ is semisimple. 
Following Wallach [W] we define a real reductive group or a reductive Lie group as follows.
Let $f_1,... , f_m$ be complex polynomials on $M(n,\mathbb{C})$ such that each $f_i$ is real-valued
on $M(n,\mathbb{R})$ and such that the set of simultaneous zeros of $f_i$ in $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ is a subgroup
$G_{\mathbb{C}}$ of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$. Then $G_{\mathbb{C}}$ is called an affine algebraic group defined over $\mathbb{R}$.
The subgroup $G_{\mathbb{R}} = G_{\mathbb{C}} \cap GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is called the group of real points. By a real
reductive group or a reductive Lie group we mean a finite covering group $G$ of an
open subgroup $G_0$ of $G_{\mathbb{R}}$.

For example, $GL(n, \mathbb{F})$ for $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ is reductive and every connected
semisimple Lie group with finite center is reductive. Thus, we can define a Cartan
involution on Lie algebra $\frak{g}$ of a reductive Lie group $G$ by $\theta(X) = −X^* = −\overline{X}^t$.

Obviously $GL(n, \mathbb{F})$ ia reductive because it's Lie-algebra is reductive. Why is every connected semisimple Lie group with finite center reductive as well?

Additionally I not understand why the Cartan involution $\theta$ on the on Lie algebra $\frak{g}$ is well defined. In other words why for $X \in \frak{g}$ the element $−\overline{X}^t$ is as well contained in $\frak{g}$?

Comment: 1. Your definition of reductive Lie groups is wrong you are missing an assumption. What you defined is a group appearing as a finite covering of an affine algebraic real Lie group. 2. The fact that semisimple real Lie groups with finite center all appear this way is nontrivial, it is discussed for instance in Chapter 5 of the book "Lie groups and algebraic groups" by Onischik and Vinberg which, I think, you can read in its original form. The key is that the complexification of a simple real Lie algebra is a complex Lie algebra and all complex simple Lie groups are algebraic.

Comment: I found several definitions of reductive Lie groups but your first sentence tells that if I would add an assumption then the definition I gave in the question becomes correct. Which additional assumption do you mean?

Comment: See for instance [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductive_group) Wikipedia article.

Comment: In my question I "defined" a reductive Lie group as a finite covering group $G$ of an open subgroup $G_0$ of $G_{\mathbb{R}}$. You wrote that my definition of reductive Lie groups is wrong and I'm missing an assumption. that is I expected to find a characterization like $G$ is reducing iff a finite covering group $G$ of an open subgroup $G_0$ of $G_{\mathbb{R}}$ AND an additional assumption I was missing. In linked Wikipedia article I not such characterization. Could you tell me which assumption my wrong "definition" missing?

Comment: The missing assumption is the existence of a completely reducible representation with finite kernel. The standard example of a non reductive algebraic group is the group of upper triangular matrices.